# cannot use strings in data in highcharts on doughnut charts

Tags: highcharts

Why can't I use strings in data on a highchart doughnut chart? You can use it on Bar charts but not doughnut for some reason?

Example of strings in data for bar chart (no errors):
[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8rsywuc7/

```
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: ['','','','','']
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
```

---

Example of strings in data for doughnut chart (see error):
[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/troqjcnz/

```
  "data": [38, 44, 14, 20, 25, 75],
  "name": "Male",
},
{
  "data": ['','','','','',''],
  "name": "Female",
},
{
  "data": [38, 44, 14, 20, 25, 75],
  "name": "No reply",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that there is a big difference between those two series configs. In the first one, the data is an array of empty string, meanwhile in the second data becomes an array of objects where y is set to empty string. If you will do the same in the column, the same error will occur - see: http://jsfiddle.net/8rsywuc7/

```
series: [{
  name: 'John',
  data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
  name: 'Jane',
  data: [{
    name: 'test',
    y: ''
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Joe',
  data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
```

What can I suggest is:

- use null rather than empty strings (I am aware that it is not the same, but the output should be similar), demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jokbgryz/
- change the logic responsible for creating data for something like is done here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9bov21gf/